# php - select data where time is same as future date

Tags: php, mysql, time, pdo, unix-timestamp

I have a table in my database, called `users_added`, inside that table, I have a field called `expire` which stores a unix timestamp.

My question is, how can I loop through **x** number of days, and see how many days the users have left (until the expire date is met)

Example:

```
    1 day remaining:
    10 users

    2 days remaining: 
    0 users

    3 days remaining 
    50 users
```

etc etc..

Graphical example:

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
    // Start date
    $date = date("Y-m-d",$time);
    // End date
    $end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . " +10 days"));



    while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)){


        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users_added WHERE user_by=:user AND expire<:time");
        $stmt->bindParam(":user",$userdata['username']);
        $stmt->bindParam(":time",$end_date);
        $stmt->execute();
        $expireData = $stmt->fetchAll();
        $remaining = $date-$end_date;
        echo "$remaining";
        echo "day(s) remaining:";

        $date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
    }
```

I can't really go further from here, as I am stuck. I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: `GROUP BY CEIL( (expire - UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) / 86400)`? I normally avoid unix timestamps in tables though. (You probably want to add `WHERE expire > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` to avoid expired users showing with negative days).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE users (expiry INT UNSIGNED);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.12 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO users (expiry) VALUES
        (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() + 1000),
        (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() + 12348),
        (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() + 89284),
        (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() + 99438),
        (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() + 333552),
        (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() + 883718),
        (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() + 994872);
Query OK, 7 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 7  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT
        ROUND((expiry - UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) / 86400) AS days,
        COUNT(*) AS cnt
       FROM users
       WHERE expiry > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
       GROUP BY days;
+------+-----+
| days | cnt |
+------+-----+
|    0 |   2 |
|    1 |   2 |
|    4 |   1 |
|   10 |   1 |
|   12 |   1 |
+------+-----+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Just let the database do the work; [subtracting](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_minus) the expiry timestamp from the current timestamp gives you the number of seconds before expiry, and dividing that by 86400 gives you number of days. Then you can [group](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html) the results by number of days, to get the count for each day.

Answer (score 2):

I would generate an array of possible dates using a while loop, then use a the max and min to run a MySQL query using BETWEEN AND
The first part would look something like:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$expdts = array();
$i = 0;
while($i<=10){
    $expdts[] = strtotime($date . " + " . $i . "days");
    $i++;
}
```

and then just run a single MySQl query of:

```
"SELECT * FROM users_added WHERE expire BETWEEN :time1 AND :time2"
```

`:time1` being `$expdts[0]` and `:time2` being `$expdts[10]`
then sort them by the expire variable. As a bouns this can be done with the $expdts array, as the keys in this array are how many 'days out' the time stamp is from the current date.

I haven't tested this past the first part.

Comment: Using the SELECT * query I get no results.

Comment: i tested it and it works for me, do you get any error messages?
whats the table look like?